# Debug on Program about Permutation

Tags: c++, permutation

Recently I am writing a program to generate a fixed number of permutation of alphabets inputted. For example, I inputted 3, 3, ABC, the program will output ABC, ACB, BAC, according to lexicographical order. But the program cannot get through all the test case and i cant find out where is the bug. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int used[26], cou = 0, k, n, i;
string output;
string sorting(string x, int y)
{
    char temp;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < y; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < y-1; ++j)
        {
            if (x[j]-'0' > x[j+1]-'0')
           {
                temp = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j+1];
                x[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}

void out(int x, string y)
{
    int i;
    if (cou == k)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (x == n+1)
    {
        cout << output << endl;
        ++cou;
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (used[i] == 0)
            {
                used[i] = 1;
                output[x-1] = y[i];
                out(x+1, y);
                used[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char inpi;
    string inp, ha;
    cin >> n >> k >> inp;
    output.resize(n);
    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        used[i] = 0;
    }
    inp = sorting(inp, n);
    out(1, inp);
}
```

Comment: I don't think "alphabet" means what you think it means.

Comment: "the program cannot get through all the test case" How do you know? You didn't say what it does or does not do either way. What did you expect to happen? _What_ happens instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understood the question.

Leaving the algorithm aside, you should know that a standard string is able to tell how long is. Therefore the `y` parameter in `sorting` is redundant. Use `x.size()` to find the size.

Another problem is `output[x] = y[i];`. You did not set `output`'s size: it is zero. Since you are looking for permutations, I assume its size must equal `y`'s size: `output.resize( y.size() );`.

One last thing: use meaningful identifiers. `y` may be good for a compiler; for a human, it may define a bad day.

Comment: I'm sure you meant `x.length()`.

Comment: @JanWinkler "Potato, potahto, tomato, tomahto!".

Comment: I always switch on `-pedantic` ;).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a need to create a global as you have done
    `string output;`

Create a string to capture the output either within main() and pass it by reference to the functions which need them, in this case fill()
or
create it within fill() and return it by value once its populated

Comment: Good point, but not really an answer. ...although to be fair, it's not like the original post has any clear question.